# Testing image uploads in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add some tests to one of my apps in a Django project. This app includes the `Image` model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from cecommerce.image_mappings import ImageAgnosticMapping
from cecoresizer.fields import ResizableImageField


class Image(models.Model):
    file = ResizableImageField(
        _("Image"),
        max_length=300,
        image_config=ImageAgnosticMapping,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

Which is then serialize using the following serializer:

```py
from django.http import Http404

from rest_framework import serializers

from cecotec_apps.landings.models import ProductLanding
from cecotec_apps.partner.models import Home

from images.models import Image


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = serializers.ImageField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {"file": str(instance)}

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ("id",)
```

I'm trying to test the creation of an `Image` instance (which works when requesting the API using Imsonia) with this test:

```py
import tempfile

from PIL import Image as ImageFile

from django.test import tag

from model_bakery import baker

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse


from cecotec_apps.landings.models import ProductLanding
from cecotec_apps.partner.models import Home

from images.api.serializers import ImageSerializer
from images.models import Image

from tests.oscar.decorator.decorator_all_methods import global_test_decorator

from user.models import User


@tag("e2e", "image")
@global_test_decorator()
class ImageTestCase(APITestCase):
    API_VERSION = "v1"
    IMAGES_QUANTITY = 20
    HTTP_HOST = "localhost:8000"

    @classmethod
    def _populate(cls):
        cls.token = baker.make(Token)
        baker.make_recipe("images.image_recipe", _quantity=cls.IMAGES_QUANTITY)

    @classmethod
    def _generate_image_file(cls):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="jpg") as tmp_file:
            image = ImageFile.new("RGB", size=(100, 100))
            image.save(tmp_file, "jpeg")
            tmp_file.seek(0)

            return tmp_file

    @classmethod
    def _depopulate(cls):
        Token.objects.all().delete()
        User.objects.all().delete()
        ProductLanding.objects.all().delete()
        Home.objects.all().delete()
        Image.objects.all().delete()

    def setUp(self, *args):
        self._depopulate()
        self._populate()

    def tearDown(self, *args):
        self._depopulate()

    @tag("create", "authenticated")
    def test_create_authenticated(self, *args):
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.token.user, token=self.token)

        data = self._prepare_create_data(**{"file": self._generate_image_file()})

        response = self._call_create(data)

        self._assert_create(response)
        self.assertRegex(response.data.get("file"), "^images\/.+$")

    def _call_create(self, data):
        return self.client.post(
            path=reverse(f"image-list"),
            data=data,
            # content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT,
            format="multipart",
            HTTP_HOST=self.HTTP_HOST,
        )

    def _assert_create(self, response, expected_status_code=201):
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, expected_status_code)

        if expected_status_code == 201:
            response_data = response.data

            self.assertEqual(Image.objects.count(), self.IMAGES_QUANTITY + 1)
            self._assert_response_body(response_data)
        else:
            self.assertEqual(Image.objects.count(), self.IMAGES_QUANTITY)

    def _assert_response_body(self, response_body):
        self.assertIn("file", response_body)
```

But, when running it the response code returned is **400 Bad Request** instead of **201 Created**. The response body is like this:

```json
{
    "file": [
        ErrorDetail(string="The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.",
        code="invalid")
    ]
}
```

I've also tried using an already created file for testing but the error was the same. I've seen lots of posts online but none is helping me with the issue.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

I think the problem comes from `_generate_image_file` method.

```py
@classmethod
def _generate_image_file(cls):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="jpg") as tmp_file:
        image = ImageFile.new("RGB", size=(100, 100))
        image.save(tmp_file, "jpeg")
        tmp_file.seek(0)

        return tmp_file
```

Since `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` is created with `with` statement, by the time you returned it and used it in another method, the file is already closed and removed.

## Solution

You should change `_generate_image_file` to be a context manager by using the decorating the method with `contextlib.contextmanager` and use `yied` statement instead of return.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
@classmethod
def _generate_image_file(cls):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="jpg") as tmp_file:
        image = ImageFile.new("RGB", size=(100, 100))
        image.save(tmp_file, "jpeg")
        tmp_file.seek(0)

        yied tmp_file
```

And on the `test_create_authenticated` method, change it to the following

```py
@tag("create", "authenticated")
def test_create_authenticated(self, *args):
    ...
    with self._generate_image_file() as image_file:
        data = self._prepare_create_data(**{"file": image_file})
        response = self._call_create(data)
    ...
```

Now the image file will be removed after the `with` block exits.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use this:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

with open("/some/path/to/image.jpg", "rb") as image:
        image = SimpleUploadedFile("image.jpg", image.read(), content_type="image/jpg")
        data = self._prepare_create_data(**{"file": image})
...
```

What happens is that your serializer is validating the file being sent is not valid. Make sure to have the `parser_classes = (parsers.MultiPartParser,)` in your View, the `models.ImageField` in your model as well.